# Incorrect notification when changing email preferences

Tags: bug, email, profile-page

Incorrect notification shown when *'Email chat event reminders, bounty expiration notices, and achievement announcements'* setting is being changed. It says *'You will no longer receive unread inbox messages via email'* even though I didn't change that setting.

Before

[image: Before]

Change

[image]

Notification

[image]